# CentOS automatic installation fails with "Installation Destination" error

Tags: anaconda, centos7, rhel, powerpc

I'm trying to install the centos netboot install on ppc64le platform but automation installation(kickstart) fails with the following error:

```
Starting installer, one moment...
find_file: stat /proc/device-tree/chosen/bootpath, No such file or directory
anaconda 21.48.22.56-1 for CentOS AltArch 7 started.
 * installation log files are stored in /tmp during the installation
 * shell is available on TTY2
 * when reporting a bug add logs from /tmp as separate text/plain attachments
Starting automated install..........
Generating updated storage configuration
storage configuration failed: failed to find a suitable stage1 device
================================================================================
================================================================================
Installation

 1) [x] Language settings                 2) [x] Timezone settings
        (English (United States))                (UTC timezone)
 3) [x] Installation source               4) [x] Software selection
        (http://mirror.centos.org/altar          (Custom software selected)
        ch/7/os/ppc64le/)                 6) [x] Kdump
 5) [!] Installation Destination                 (Kdump is enabled)b | Help: F1 
        (Error checking storage configu
        ration)
 7) [x] Network configuration
        (Wired (enp0s1) connected)

** (anaconda:1253): WARNING **: Could not open X display

The installation was stopped due to incomplete spokes detected while running in non-interactive cmdline mode. Since there cannot be any questions in cmdline mode, edit your kickstart file and retry installation.
The exact error message is: 

The following mandatory spokes are not completed:
Installation Destination.

The installer will now terminate.

[root@llmtul01b qemu]#
```

And kickstart file looks like:

```
url --url="http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/ppc64le/"
install
keyboard us
rootpw --lock --iscrypted locked
timezone --isUtc --nontp UTC
selinux --enforcing
firewall --disabled
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=link --activate --onboot=on
reboot
bootloader --disable
lang en_US

# Repositories to use 
repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/ppc64le/ --cost=100
## Uncomment for rolling builds
repo --name="Updates" --baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/updates/ppc64le/ --cost=100

# Disk setup
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part / --fstype ext4 --size=3000
```

Looking for the option to select the installation destination through kickstart file.

Answer (score 0):

This problem solved by adding one more partition which is specific for ppc64le pltform.

Update and working kickstart file looks like :

```
url --url="http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/ppc64le/"
install
keyboard us
rootpw --lock --iscrypted locked
timezone --isUtc --nontp UTC
selinux --enforcing
firewall --disabled
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=link --activate --onboot=on
reboot
bootloader --disable
lang en_US

# Repositories to use 
repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/os/ppc64le/ --cost=100
## Uncomment for rolling builds
repo --name="Updates" --baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/updates/ppc64le/ --cost=100

# Disk setup
zerombr
clearpart --all --initlabel
part / --fstype ext4 --size=3000
part prepboot --fstype "PPC PReP Boot" --size=10
```

Comment: I added the missing partition to the answer.